# Get Value of ID after JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two TextBoxFor fields that utilize autocomplete.  After they're filled by either selected autocomplete values or manual values, other javascript functions are blank when referencing the ID.val().  What needs to be added/changed to get these values?  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Pre-populating the field in the Controller before sending to the View allows the function call to retrieve the correct, pre-populated value.  It appears that the field value is not recognized only if the user tries to edit the field and/or use autocomplete.

**EDIT2:** I've tried binding the function to document.ready followed by on click, and document.on click, and neither one finds a value in the textbox ID.

Razor:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddedWorkmate, "Workmate To Add", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddedWorkmate, new { data_autocomplete_url = Url.Action("GetWorkmates"), @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="button" id="bUser" name="bUserButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Workmate Recipient</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
function ExampleFunction() {
    var $addedW = $("#AddedWorkmate");//This should work, but apparently doesn't
    var textTest = $addedW.text(),// = ""
        valueTest = $addedW.val();// = ""
    //Stuff to do
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a sloppy mistake behind all of this: the field was declared as a @HiddenFor earlier in the webpage.  That line was removed after seeing the input was "hidden" on the source code, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the input will not detect the change if you type in the autocomplete and you still have the focus. Have you tried to escape the textbox and call `ExampleFunction` aftewards?

You could also bind `ExampleFunction` on `input` event of this textbox.`input` is triggered on user typing or pasting so it also should work with the autocomplete.

```
(function(){
      $('#AddedWorkmate').on("input", ExampleFunction);
   }
)();

function ExampleFunction() {
    var text = $(this).val();
}
```

**Edit:**

Try the following steps:

1. Leave up the autocomple. Type or paste some text into the `m => m.AddedWorkmate` textbox e.g. `test`.
2. Open console.
3. Type and call `$("#AddedWorkmate).val()`.
4. You should get a response of `"test"`.
5. If you have this - you don't have a bug within the DOM.
6. Then try to bind an event on `input` like so

```
(function(){
      $('#AddedWorkmate').on("input", function(){console.log('test')});
   }
)();
```

7. If this logs into the console on input - yay you have a proper binding.
8. Then focus on getting the value. At this point it has to be inside of `$(this).val()`, I don't see any other possibility. If it is not undefined and the value is still empty you are doing sth wrong outside of the scope of the question.
9. If you succeed to get the value, then join it with the autocomplete - it should work.

Comment: thanks for the answer!  I have tried clicking outside the textbox before pressing the button that fires the function, and the value is still "".  I'll try binding the function to the input of the textbox.

Comment: I tried putting the example code in, and the input code doesn't get fired.  The ExampleFunction only gets fired when the button gets pushed.

Comment: Are you sure the id of this TextBoxFor renders to _AddedWorkmate_? Please verify that you can use $('#AddedWorkmate').val() with e,g, manually typed text. I don't have the full context so I might be missing sth.

Comment: It appears to be the actual ID.  Viewing the source, it's id = "AddedWorkmate".  I thought it was something along the lines of what you originally proposed regarding maybe the focus of the autocomplete, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't know then. I think you have a bug somewhere outside of this scope which I can't tell. At this point you should be able to call $('#AddedWorkmate').val() and get whatever you typed in before whatever you do on the button click. Try to verify that you don't have any other elements with same id and that input event binding is being called properly.

Comment: Check out the edit, I hope you find the solution step by step, good luck :).

Comment: I just tried pre-populating the field to open the View, and pressing the button/calling the function does in fact get the right .val().  It seems to be only when the user adds to the previously blank input that the value doesn't get passed.

Answer (score 0):

Add the id you want to the textbox so you can reference it from jQuery.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddedWorkmate, new { data_autocomplete_url = Url.Action("GetWorkmates"), @class = "form-control", id="AddedWorkmate" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't seem to work.  The id was added just like the example, and the .val() still reads "".